# vb.net Formatting data structure input for web service

Tags: arrays, vb.net, service

I need to format an input data structure for an RPG web service. I've tried using a list and it does not work. When I try this code:

```
Dim clist As New List(Of LabelView.PASSBACK.dscustomers)
clist.Add(New LabelView.PASSBACK.dscustomers() With {.BALANCEDUE = 185.42, .CREATIONDATE = 20200101, .CUSTOMERID = 1, .CUSTOMERTYPE = "ACTIVE", .FIRSTNAME = "Pat", .LASTNAME = "Smith"})
clist.Add(New LabelView.PASSBACK.dscustomers() With {.BALANCEDUE = 185.42, .CREATIONDATE = 20200101, .CUSTOMERID = 2, .CUSTOMERTYPE = "ACTIVE", .FIRSTNAME = "Jordan", .LASTNAME = "Jones"})

input.DSCUSTOMERS = clist
// ^^ Intellisense error:
// Value of type 'List (Of dsCustomers)' cannot be converted to 'dscustomers()'.
```

I can't figure out how to programmatically build something compatible. When I try this:

```
Dim client As PASSBACK.PASSBACK = New PASSBACK.PASSBACK()
Dim input As PASSBACK.passbackInput = New PASSBACK.passbackInput
input.DSCUSTOMERS(0).FIRSTNAME = "Hello"
```

It compiles but when I run I get 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: What are you trying to do with your modified list?  Use it internally?  Send it back out somewhere?  Most likely, the easiest way to add a new item is to have the member be a `List(Of T)` instead of an array.

Comment: I've revamped my question to better describe what I'm trying to do. I've tried List and it does not work for this scenario.

Comment: You can fix your immediate error above by assigning `clist.ToArray()`.  This will convert the list into a new array and assign it to `DSCUSTOMERS`.  I'm not sure if `ToArray` is a member of `List(Of T)` or if it's an extension method from Linq, if the latter, you would also need `Imports System.Linq` at the top of the file.

Comment: I think the .ToArray() might be the trick! I'm making some headway now, THANK YOU. (I'm so new to this I don't even see how to mark your comment as an answer.)

Comment: You can't mark it as an answer because it's not an answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue with this line:

```
input.DSCUSTOMERS = clist
```

Is because `DCUSTOMERS` is an array (the "dcustomers()" of your error message) and  a `List(Of dcustomer)` can't be directly assigned to an array.

There is a conversion function on `List(Of T)` that will give you an array `T()` called `ToArray`.  It requires only a small change to your code:

```
input.DSCUSTOMERS = clist.ToArray()
```

This will make a new array with the same contents as the `List` (if `dcustomers` is a `Class` then the contents of the array will be exactly the same objects, whereas if it's a `Structure` then they will be copies) and assign it to `DCUSTOMERS`.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you 1000x. .ToArray in conjunction with the List has it working! I tried so many things, you have helped us out mucho with this. This was a big missing puzzle piece in being able to talk back and forth between AS400 programs and vb.net